# In bootstrap How to keep navbar for multiple page with out reload it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a admin app with Bootstrap and angular js. I am using navbar for the header. For each link it should load different page. How should I load each page with out reloading the navbar.

My index file code is attached. I have copied the navbar code in each file(all the site.html). I know this is not a proper solution. May I know, what are the options available to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Radar </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/site1.html">site1</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/site2.html">site2</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/site3.html">site3</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/site4.html">site4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                        Hi Anand </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                        Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What languages and frameworks are you using? .NET? MVC? PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a master page with your code with a div added.  Then load our other pages inside of the div.

...

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Radar </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/site1.html">site1</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/site2.html">site2</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/site3.html">site3</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/site4.html">site4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    Hi Anand </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                    Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="pagediv">

</div>
```

example of javascript:

```
document.getElementById("pagediv").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="pages/site1.html" ></object>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a header and attach a controller to it. And keep an outlet for separate pages after header. This way all the links will load there template in the outlet and header will not reload.

Answer (score 1):

Use ui router to maintain states. It has concept of parent states ans child states.In your code Parent will be navbar and child will be site.html pages..
So there will common navbar for all site pages.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router